# write_dynamic_array_formula() formula works but I have to press enter to apply

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a table containing coordinates with associated labels A, B and C. I want to add another column that simply translates the labels to 1, 2 and 3.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create some example data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
labels = ["A", "B", "C", "B", "A"]

# Create a new Excel file and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('scatter_plot.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Data')

# write column headings
worksheet.write(0,0,'x')
worksheet.write(0,1,'y')
worksheet.write(0,2,'labels')


# Write the data to the worksheet
for i in range(len(x)):
    worksheet.write(i+1, 0, x[i])
    worksheet.write(i+1, 1, y[i])
    worksheet.write(i+1, 2, labels[i])

# Formula that writes a new column where A = 1 B = 2 C = 3    
worksheet.write_dynamic_array_formula('D2:D6', '=IFS(LEFT(C2:C6,1)="A",1,LEFT(C2:C6,1)="B",2,LEFT(C2:C6,1)="C",3,TRUE,NA())')    

# Add a scatter chart to the worksheet
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
chart.add_series({
    'name':       'X vs Y',
    'categories': '=Data!$A$2:$A$6',
    'values':     '=Data!$B$2:$B$6',
    
})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet
worksheet.insert_chart("F1", chart)

# Save the Excel file
workbook.close()
```

I run this and get this excel file output:[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Ldw.png)

The formula has no syntax errors in excel, I just have to manually press enter on the cell for it to apply the formula. Shouldn't this be done automatically?

Comment: From the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html): *XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened.*

Comment: Is there a way to calculate it automatically, so that when I open the file the cells have already been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IFS()` is a so called Future Function in Excel and generally needs to be prefixed by `_xlfn.` (which won't show up in the formula in Excel):

```py
worksheet.write_dynamic_array_formula('D2:D6', '=_xlfn.IFS(LEFT(C2:C6,1)="A",1,LEFT(C2:C6,1)="B",2,LEFT(C2:C6,1)="C",3,TRUE,NA())')
```

Or you can use the `use_future_functions` [Constructor](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor) option.

```py
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('scatter_plot.xlsx', {'use_future_functions': True})
```

Either of those changes will produce the desired result:

[image]

For more information see the  [Formulas added in Excel 2010](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-future) section of the XlsxWriter docs.