# I need to press "enter" on a VSTACK formula containing multiple filter formulas for it to work, after using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am using python with xlsxwriter. On the generated sheet, I have it inserting a vstack formula that contains multiple filter formulas.

Upon first opening of the excel sheet, it has #NAME? in the field, but when I put my curser into the formula and press enter, the formula then works properly.

I've tried inserting just the filter functions on their own, and it works as expected, but VSTACK tends to have an issue.

Any ideas as to how I can fix it?

Python formula:

```
formula = '=VSTACK(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Add!A:N,Add!A:A="Add"),{1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),""),IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Remove!G:R,(Remove!G:G="Remove")*(Remove!F:F=B1)),{1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),""),IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(Remove!G:R,(Remove!G:G="Retain")*(Remove!F:F=B1)),{1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),""))'
worksheet.write_dynamic_array_formula('A11', formula)
```

Comment: That's not a function of xlsxwriter. Maybe this post will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216155/write-dynamic-array-formula-formula-works-but-i-have-to-press-enter-to-apply)

Comment: Have you check in your excel version you have `VSTACK` available? try to use it alone and see it if works

Comment: hi @DavidLeal, vstack definitely works in my excel. when i type it from scratch, it works automatically, it's just when it's inserted by xlsxwriter, i need to press "enter" on it for it to start filling

Comment: hi @moken, no it's not an xlsxwriter function but its an excel function. I did try adding the '_xlfn.' before the function, as suggested in the post, but it makes excel come up with an error when I open it after :(

Comment: 'function' is probably not the best word to have used there given we are talking about Excel. I meant is is not part of xlsxwriter operation to calculate formulas. Anyway sorry to hear that post didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The `VSTACK` function is relatively new to the Excel and isn't currently supported automatically by XlsxWriter. In the meantime you can add the explicit [future function](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later) prefixes to your formula like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet("Add")
worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet("Remove")


formula = '_xlfn.VSTACK(IFERROR(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(Add!A:N,Add!A:A="Add"),{1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),""),IFERROR(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(Remove!G:R,(Remove!G:G="Remove")*(Remove!F:F=B1)),{1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),""),IFERROR(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(Remove!G:R,(Remove!G:G="Retain")*(Remove!F:F=B1)),{1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),""))'

worksheet.write_dynamic_array_formula('A11', formula)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

I've added a [Feature Request](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/984) to XlsxWriter to ensure it gets fixed in an upcoming release. **Update:** Fixed in version 3.1.1.

Comment: Thanks so much Jmcnamara :) Love the library, by the way. It is awesome. So helpful!